# jQuery Mobile Dynamic Content and Browser History

Tags: jquery-mobile, browser-history, dynamic-content

I'm developing a mobile app using jquery mobile and I have a page that I dynamically fill from an AJAX web service call.  That creates a list of links that then filter the page down further.  For instance the first time the page loads it gets all categories that are assigned to the root category (0 in this case).  Each list item then contains a category parameter which is each categories ID.  But this means that when you click a sub item in the list it loads the next level down.

The problem I'm having is with history.  If I drill down the list and click the back button it takes me right back to category list page but with parameter 0 instead of the last page I was on which might be category ID 2.

Does jquery mobile not keep history correctly when creating dynamic pages.

I have followed this example and can't figure out why the history is not working correctly http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html.

I have this code in the navigation bar that takes you to the initial category list page:

```html
<li><a href="#category_page?category=0" id="shop-button" data-icon="custom" data-transition="none">Shop</a></li>
```

I then populate the page with the following code:

```js
var webServiceURL = "http://localhost/GV/mobileservices/AppsWebService.asmx";

function getCategories(parentId) {
var parameters = "{'parentID':" + parentId + "}";
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
$('#categoriesList').empty();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webServiceURL + "/GetCategories",
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        var t = "";
        data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        categoriesJSON = data;
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            t = t + "<li><a href=\"#category_page?category=" + item.CategoryID + "\" title=\"" + item.CategoryTitle + "\">" + item.CategoryName + "</a></li>";
        });
        $('#categoriesList').append(t).listview('refresh');
        $('#categoriesContent').iscrollview("refresh");
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});    
};

function showCategory(urlObj, options) {
var categoryID = urlObj.hash.replace(/.*category=/, "");
var pageSelector = urlObj.hash.replace(/\?.*$/, "");
var $page = $(pageSelector),
$header = $page.children(":jqmData(role=header)");

$header.find("div").find("h3").html("Category");
$page.page();
options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;
$.mobile.changePage($page, options);
setTimeout("getCategories(" + categoryID + ")", 100);
}

// Listen for any attempts to call changePage().
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {

if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {
    var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage),
        re = /^#category_page/;
    if (u.hash.search(re) !== -1) {
        showCategory(u, data.options);
       e.preventDefault();
    }
}
});
```

Can someone help me out ? Can I manually add each page/url to the history when I create the dynamic page ?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: I've also noticed that the url does not change at all from http://localhost/gvapp/index.html#category_page?category=0 when I navigate down.  When I navigate down then the url should change to http://localhost/gvapp/index.html#category_page?category=137